# Aid in finding algebra step-by-step validator tool/application?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, math-software

I'm looking for an online tool/application that will validate my algebra moves at each step I do them. I'm picturing a text line where I can enter the starting equation, then type in the next step which alters that starting equation, then have the program validate or invalidate that move.

I know of the programs that solve equations along with detailing the algebra steps. But they aren't quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to validate each of my own steps at a time rather than viewing how to get to the answer with a bunch of steps they did. This stems from often having different steps in my work compared to the program. It's frustrating if I'm attempting to see where I went wrong in my work. I could validate each step quickly if my steps were the same listed on the site.

Does anyone know of anything like I'm describing?

Thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha has a "step by step solution" option, will this work for you?  Example: go here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+3x%2B2y%3D1+and+4x-y%3D7 and click "step by step solution".

Comment: You could use the $===$ operator in wolframalpha to confirm equality of two expressions. Eg https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%28a%2Bb%29+%3D%3D%3D+a%5E2%2Bab

Comment: Sorry it should be the $==$ operator and not $===$. See here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html

Comment: Note: The $==$ operator will return $true$ if the expressions are equivalent otherwise it treats the double equals as a single equal sign and tries to solve the resulting equation